# Will Babel polyfill old features that exist but don't fully conform to targeted standard?

Tags: javascript, babel-polyfill

I'm using Babel targeting ES2020 and trying to figure out whether I can rely on `Object.keys` to enumerate keys in the order specified by ES2020.

I understand that:

- [ES2020 guarantees a specific enumeration order for Object.keys, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)
- In ES2015-2019, the `Object.keys` feature existed but enumeration order wasn't specified
- Babel provides polyfills which allow older browsers to use features that they are entirely missing

But I can't figure out whether Babel will polyfill features that are implemented in ways that don't conform to the targeted standard.

If an older browser implements a feature in a way that doesn't conform to the targeted standard, will Babel polyfill it to ensure that its behavior is standard-compliant?

Thanks for reading!

---

#### Example

Firefox 4.0.1 implements `Object.keys` such that numeric keys are not always displayed before string keys as required in ES2020.

```
> var fruit = {"banana": 1, "apple": 2, "tomato": 3, 100: 4}
> Object.keys(fruit)
>>> ["banana", "apple", "tomato", "100"]
```

Firefox 88.0.1:

```
> var fruit = {"banana": 1, "apple": 2, "tomato": 3, 100: 4}
> Object.keys(fruit)
>>> Array(4) [ "100", "banana", "apple", "tomato" ]
```

Comment: can you give us an example which browser implements a feature in a non-standard way?

Comment: Example added showing Firefox 4.0.1 implements Object.keys in a way that does not comply with ES2020.

Comment: Good code doesn't rely on the enumeration order of object properties anyway, so this would be a low-priority issue for babel. The order was only standardised to make the spec more deterministic and avoid incompatibilities between engines, not because code should make use of this.

Comment: @Bergi: Sure, if enumeration order is important, it makes sense to default to a map rather than an object. However, in Typescript I've been unable to type a readonly map as thoroughly as I can an object. The compiler can't know at compile time which keys the map should have without an explicit check before each use. Because I can make objects both safer and more ergonomic than a map, I think it's worth using an object **if** I can guarantee that it will behave predictably.